# how can I get modules export in a webpack's plugin?

Tags: webpack

Is there any way to get module's export in a `webpack-plugin`?

I try to get module's export by write a `webpack plugin`, is it possibly?

Please tell me, thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more specific information?

Comment: I want to get a javascript file's export in a webpack plugin, is there any way to achieve？For example: there is a file a.js:<code> //do something...   module.exports=function(){console.log('123');} </code>. How can I get the module.exports?

Comment: Just `require` these files you need import.

Comment: Thanks. I know just require these files can get what I need. But I want to get it from the state of webpack compiler, is it probably?

Answer (score 0):

```
  function Plugin(options) {}

  Plugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
    compiler.plugin('emit', function(compilation, callback) {
      for (var filename in compilation.assets) {
        //do some things here.
      }
      callback();
    });
  };

  module.exports = Plugin;
```

Comment: I have try to run your suggest, but I didn't get what I want. Do you mean to require the file once more?

Comment: Yes, maybe there are some better solution, we can take a look at some plugin's source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I search for some plugin which  achieve my idea. If you get any new idea or find some plugin about this, please tell to me. Thanks.